# How to set background color for Textview programmatically for another xml file?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

hi am new to android how to set text background color for another xml file in programatically am already add xml file using set content view but it have only listview only and i have one another xml file using module for executing file,i want to text background in modelo xml file

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
    EXECUTAR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_buscar);
    ValorBusca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_buscar);
    Lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ValorBusca.setText("");
    EXECUTAR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            QuerySQL(null);
        }
    });
}
    public  void QuerySQL(String COMANDOSQL) {
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        Statement statement = ma.connect.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ValorBusca.getText().toString()+"");
        List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            Map<String, String> datanum =new HashMap<String, String>();
            datanum.put("A",rs.getString(1));
            datanum.put("B",rs.getString(2));
            datanum.put("c",rs.getString(3));
            data.add(datanum);  
        }

        String[] from = {"A","B","c"};
        int[] views = {R.id.txttitulo,R.id.txtconteudo,R.id.textview3};
        AD = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.modelo, from, views);
        Lista.setAdapter(AD);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO",e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Enter Table Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and i want text background in this file modelo

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
 >

 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="2dip"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txttitulo" 
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="2dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:padding="5dip"

        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textColor="#0174DF"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtconteudo" 
        android:text="Number"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="2dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#0174DF"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:padding="5dip" 
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3" 
        android:text="Number"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="2dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="#0174DF"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:padding="5dip" 
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: you want to change bg color af all the textview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way. Just override `getView()` method of you adapter. And change color from there.

```
AD = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.modelo, from, views){
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View v = convertView;
if (v == null) {
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.modelo, null);
}
TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txttitulo);
TextView text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtconteudo);
TextView text3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview3);
text1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
text2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
text3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
return super.getView(position, v, parent);
}
};
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: sorry it is working in android studio!! but not working in eclipse it will show to create class file or interface

Answer (score 8):

Check this one,

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
textView.setText("Welcome");
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 4):

This may be Help You.

```
textview.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
```

**Note** :instead of **textview** you need to write your **TextView object** name.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
View v=findViewById(R.layout.modelo);
TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txttitulo);
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin;

defination textview globaly :

```
lateinit var option1: TextView
```

initialize in onCreate() method

```
option1 = findViewById(R.id.option1)
```

set background color from color.xml

```
option1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorBlue)
```